# XML Serialize and Deserialize Issue for Complicated XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

**My XML**
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ServerConfig loggingEnabled="1">
      <Servers id="2" host="mytest">
        <Server host="test1.example.com" port="9999" >
           <Name id="newname1">
            <FirstName id="myfirstname">hello first name</FirstName>
            <SecondName id="myfirstname">hello first name</SecondName>
           </Name>
      </Server>
      <Server host="test2.example.com" port="8888" />
      </Servers>
      <Servers id="1">
        <Server host="test3.example.com" port="9899" >
          <Name id="newname2">
            <FirstName id="myfirstname">hello first name</FirstName>
          </Name>
        </Server>
        <Server host="test4.example.com" port="8988" />
      </Servers>
    </ServerConfig>`

I want to deserialize this xml to my class

**Class**

```
public sealed class ServerConfig
{
public sealed class Server
{
    [XmlAttribute("host")]
    public string Host { get; set; } // gives me host name

    [XmlAttribute("port")]
    public int Port { get; set; } // gives my prot number
}

[XmlArray]
public List<Server> Servers { get; set; } // gives me all 4 server lsit

[XmlAttribute("loggingEnabled")]
public int LoggingEnabled { get; set; } // gives me attribute detail

public ServerConfig()
{
    Servers = null;
    LoggingEnabled = 0;
}

}
```

**Problem**

My Problem is I don't know how to access the Attributes of the nested Element Name and sub nested element `FirstName/SecondName`

WIll be really very thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: Your classes look **nothing like** the xml you are trying to map. It **doesn't work that way**. Your best bet here would be to run `xsd.exe my.xml` and then `xsd.exe /classes my.xsd`

Comment: Sorry @MarcGravell where to run `xsd.exe my.xml and then xsd.exe /classes my.xsd` these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is being provided by Microsoft in VS 2012 onwards which is being brilliantly explained in this link.

**[XML TO C# Class](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11137/)**

All you need to do is copy your xml and then paste special to a class as explained in the link.

Happy Coding.

Thanks,